# Currency picklist values in VF differ from Standard Layout to VF page

Tags: visualforce, multi-currency

Is there any reason or counter-measure against the fact that Currency picklist values are different on VF pages than on Standard Layouts?

**Standard Layout Edit Mode:**

[image]

**VF page with apex:inputField:**

[image]

Comment: There is a standard field in salesforce called CurrencyISOCode. You can put it on your layout.

Comment: That's what I am doing already?!

Comment: Are you using <apex:outputField> ?

Comment: @AmitBangad: No <apex:inputField>!

Comment: Ok. Can you try using that  and see if you get it right ?

Comment: @AmitBangad: Sorry but this is a somewhat lame answer "Use outputfields" when someone is having problems with input fields :-(

Comment: Sorry, It was super-lame :) I was thinking something else... I thought you are generating the picklist in controller..  inputfield is fine too and if you get above screen on inputfield then the question is still open.. let me try out a POC and I ll get back..

Comment: According to [this Apex Doc](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_currencytype.htm) the picklist Label that's needed is `Currency ISO Code` to get the 3 letter choices used in the standard page layouts provided your org has them enabled.

Comment: @Robert - did you find any workaround for this? This is really odd that Currency ISO Code field renders so differently in Standard Layout and in VF Page.

Comment: I don't have any multi-currency orgs to test with, but why can't you use [CurrencyType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_currencytype.htm) to build a `List<SelectOption>` that has what you need?

Answer (score 1):

We can fulfill this requirment by our custom describe Sobject call. I would like to provide you the working code/solution for this problem. Code is given below:-

Visualforce page:-

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Currency ISO Code">   
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:selectList id="countries" value="{!Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode}" size="1" required="true">
              <apex:selectOptions value="{!CurrencyValues}"/>
            </apex:selectList>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Apex Class:-

```
public class CurrencyClass{


    public CurrencyClass (ApexPages.StandardController ctr){
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getCurrencyValues()
    {
      List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

       Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode.getDescribe();

       List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

       for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
       {
          //Concatinating currency values like  ( value "USD" label "U.S. Dollar" ) 

          string finalvalue= f.getValue() + ' - ' + f.getLabel() ;

          options.add(new SelectOption(finalvalue, finalvalue));
       }       
       return options;
    }

}
```